# How to select 2 periods of date in sql qliksense

Tags: sql, oracle

I do a request in oracle sql

I got this :

```
select Px,qte 
from dwh_dfh

where date_jour > '01/01/2022;
```

for today, I would like to have in my condition "where" :
`where date_jour between  01/01/2022 and 22/05/2022 and  date_jour between 01/01/2023 and 22/05/2023`

and for tomorrow, it will be

`where date_jour between  01/01/2022 and 23/05/2022 and date_jour between 01/01/2023 and 23/05/2023`

ect ...

I would like to know how to automate this.

Thanks for reading me

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the ranges:

- from the start of the previous year until 12 months before any time yesterday; and
- from the start of the current year until any time yesterday

then:

```sql
select Px,
       qte 
from   dwh_dfh
WHERE  (   date_jour >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), -12)
       AND date_jour <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12) )
OR     (   date_jour >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')
       AND date_jour <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) );
```